# Using TensorFlow.js I can't get through model.fit Error when checking input: expected dense_Dense1_input to have 3 dimension(s)

Tags: typescript, machine-learning, tensor, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to train my app to train and predict stock market just to understand the machine learning.
I've got the idea from jinglescode.github.io/time-series-forecasting-tensorflowjs
but when I tried to implement into my code just to test his concept with multiple input and close price for output. it show me that error
here is the code

```
async function testcode() {
  arima_pred = [];
  arima_real = [];

  try {
    const data = await getQuotes("AAPL", { interval: "5m", range: '2d' });
    let lengthData = [];
    let rawData = [];
    let rawClose = [];
    let i = 0;

    for (const dd of data.reverse()) {
      if (dd.close > 0) {
        if (i < 20) {
          arima_real.push(dd.close);

        } else {
          lengthData.push([Number(dd.open), Number(dd.high), Number(dd.low), Number(dd.close), Number(dd.volume)]);
          rawData.push(Number(dd.open));
          rawData.push(Number(dd.high));
          rawData.push(Number(dd.low));
          rawData.push(Number(dd.close));
          rawData.push(Number(dd.volume));
          rawClose.push(Number(dd.close));
        }
      }
      i++;
    }

    console.log('tst test rawdata 1:', data);
    console.log('tst test rawData: ', rawData, 'rawClose: ', rawClose);
    let Xlength = lengthData[0].length
    let Xlengtharray = rawData.length / Xlength
    let X = rawData.reverse();
    let Y = rawClose.reverse();
    let window_size = 1;
    let n_epochs = 50;
    let learning_rate = 0.01;
    let n_layers = 4;

    const batch_size = 32;

    // input dense layer
    const input_layer_shape = window_size;
    const input_layer_neurons = 64;

    // LSTM
    const rnn_input_layer_features = 16;
    const rnn_input_layer_timesteps = input_layer_neurons / rnn_input_layer_features;
    //const rnn_input_shape = [rnn_input_layer_features, rnn_input_layer_timesteps]; // the shape have to match input layer's shape
    const rnn_input_shape = [Xlengtharray, Xlength]; // the shape have to match input layer's shape

    const rnn_output_neurons = 16; // number of neurons per LSTM's cell

    // output dense layer
    const output_layer_shape = rnn_output_neurons; // dense layer input size is same as LSTM cell
    const output_layer_neurons = 1; // return 1 value

    // ## new: load data into tensor and normalize data

    const inputTensor = tf.tensor2d(X, [Xlengtharray, Xlength]).expandDims();
    const labelTensor = tf.tensor2d(Y, [Y.length, 1]).reshape([Y.length, 1]).expandDims();

    const [xs, inputMax, inputMin] = normalizeTensorFit(inputTensor);
    const [ys, labelMax, labelMin] = normalizeTensorFit(labelTensor);

    // ## define model

    const model = tf.sequential();
console.log('tst dense:')
    model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: input_layer_neurons, inputShape: rnn_input_shape }));
    console.log('tst reshape:')
    model.add(tf.layers.reshape({ targetShape: rnn_input_shape }));

    console.log('tst layers:')
  let lstm_cells = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < n_layers; index++) {
      lstm_cells.push(tf.layers.lstmCell({ units: rnn_output_neurons }));
    }
    console.log('tst rnn:')

    model.add(tf.layers.rnn({
      cell: lstm_cells,
      inputShape: rnn_input_shape,
      returnSequences: false
    }));
    console.log('tst dense output:')

    model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: output_layer_neurons, inputShape: [output_layer_shape] }));
    console.log('tst compile:')

    model.compile({
      optimizer: tf.train.adam(learning_rate),
      loss: 'meanSquaredError'
    });
    console.log('tst summary',model.summary())
    // ## fit model
console.log('tst fit:')

    const hist = await model.fit(xs, ys,
      {
        batchSize: batch_size, epochs: n_epochs, callbacks: {
          onEpochEnd: async (epoch, log) => {
            console.log(epoch, log);
          }
        }
      });

  } catch (err) {
    console.log('tst err', err);
  }
}

function normalizeTensorFit(tensor) {
  const maxval = tensor.max();
  const minval = tensor.min();
  const normalizedTensor = normalizeTensor(tensor, maxval, minval);
  return [normalizedTensor, maxval, minval];
}

function normalizeTensor(tensor, maxval, minval) {
  const normalizedTensor = tensor.sub(minval).div(maxval.sub(minval));
  return normalizedTensor;
}

function unNormalizeTensor(tensor, maxval, minval) {
  const unNormTensor = tensor.mul(maxval.sub(minval)).add(minval);
  return unNormTensor;
}
```

I get this error in console.log

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lTjR.png)

I tried this modification in model.fit

```
const hist = await model.fit(xs, ys.reshape([Y.length, 1]),
      {
        batchSize: batch_size, epochs: n_epochs, callbacks: {
          onEpochEnd: async (epoch, log) => {
            console.log(epoch, log);
          }
        }
      });
```

this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NowH6.png)

I tried many way to change the shape but I feel I'm going into a loop!